# Google email markup tester fails to validate JSON-LD for FlightReservation

Tags: html-email, json-ld, google-schemas

[Google Email Markup](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) fails to validate JSON-LD that I took from schema.org for [FlightReservation](https://schema.org/FlightReservation).

Markup tools says that type of "boardingPolicy" is wrong and "airline" field is missing, it's easy to test yourself: just copy the code below and paste it [there](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/).

Does anyone know what I can fix this?

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FlightReservation",
  "reservationId": "RXJ34P",
  "reservationStatus": "ReservationConfirmed",
  "passengerPriorityStatus": "Fast Track",
  "passengerSequenceNumber": "ABC123",
  "securityScreening": "TSA PreCheck",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Eva Green"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Flight",
    "flightNumber": "UA110",
    "provider": {
      "@type": "Airline",
      "name": "Continental",
      "iataCode": "CO",
      "boardingPolicy": "ZoneBoardingPolicy"
    },
    "seller": {
      "@type": "Airline",
      "name": "United",
      "iataCode": "UA"
    },
    "departureAirport": {
      "@type": "Airport",
      "name": "San Francisco Airport",
      "iataCode": "SFO"
    },
    "departureTime": "2017-03-04T20:15:00-08:00",
    "arrivalAirport": {
      "@type": "Airport",
      "name": "John F. Kennedy International Airport",
      "iataCode": "JFK"
    },
    "arrivalTime": "2017-03-05T06:30:00-05:00"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace *reservationD* with *reservationNumber*.

I don't think *boardingPolicy* is a supported. In the documentation it states "*Note: Some of the schemas used by Google are still going through the standardization process of schema.org, and therefore, may change in the future.*"

Instead of *seller*, you should input *airline*.

I've copied your script and modified a few attributes and received no errors with this example (if you're trying to trigger Google Now cards, I recommend to use a date/time that's a few hours away):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FlightReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "RXJ34P",
  "reservationStatus": "ReservationConfirmed",
  "passengerPriorityStatus": "Fast Track",
  "passengerSequenceNumber": "ABC123",
  "securityScreening": "TSA PreCheck",
  "underName": {
 "@type": "Person",
 "name": "Eva Green"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
 "@type": "Flight",
 "flightNumber": "UA110",
 "provider": {
   "@type": "Airline",
   "name": "Continental",
   "iataCode": "CO"
 },
 "airline": {
   "@type": "Airline",
   "name": "United",
   "iataCode": "UA"
 },
 "departureAirport": {
   "@type": "Airport",
   "name": "San Francisco Airport",
   "iataCode": "SFO"
 },
 "departureTime": "2016-03-04T20:15:00-08:00",
 "arrivalAirport": {
   "@type": "Airport",
   "name": "John F. Kennedy International Airport",
   "iataCode": "JFK"
 },
 "arrivalTime": "2016-03-05T06:30:00-05:00"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a link with a json-ld and microdata example that Google accepts:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/flight-reservation

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "FlightReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "RXJ34P",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Eva Green"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Flight",
    "flightNumber": "110",
    "airline": {
      "@type": "Airline",
      "name": "United",
      "iataCode": "UA"
    },
    "departureAirport": {
      "@type": "Airport",
      "name": "San Francisco Airport",
      "iataCode": "SFO"
    },
    "departureTime": "2017-03-04T20:15:00-08:00",
    "arrivalAirport": {
      "@type": "Airport",
      "name": "John F. Kennedy International Airport",
      "iataCode": "JFK"
    },
    "arrivalTime": "2017-03-05T06:30:00-05:00"
  }
}
</script>
```